# DKA30A DC/DC regulator TRIM

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, trim

I am trying to use the TRIM pin on the DKA30A-12 DC/DC converter to get the desired voltage.

Here is the only [datasheet](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/Dka30/DKA30-spec.pdf) available.
[image: External output trimming]

What resistor/trimmer value should I choose for the VR?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've redrawn it for you because sometimes mud is hard to see through: -

[image]

There is just a single 500 kΩ pot to connect across +V and -V and the wiper goes to the trim pin. It took me nearly a minute to figure out what they were trying to impart. Note this: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so so much, now it makes perfect sense!